# Email reading and storing scraped data in a Spring based app

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-batch

I am working on Spring Boot based server which offers REST endpoints. It is typical Controller - Service - Spring Data app.

In a new requirement, i have to scrape emails from multiple email folders and use some of these Service - Spring Data components to store the information extracted through scraping.

The email scraping has to be scheduled (or run as a job) in a Spring context. This program might be horizontally scaled over multiple AWS instances running REST server described above.

**Question**: 
I have following options to run the email reading, scraping job.
**1**. Develop a **REST endpoint** that is intended to do this operation and a **CRON Job** that runs a script which makes this REST call periodically.
**2**. Check the feasibility of using **Spring Batch** that initiate the job which directly invoke the Service - Spring Data components to persist data.

Please suggest if Spring Batch makes a good architectural choice here considering scalability required for this component.

Thanks for your time! In case you have a parallel option, please suggest that too. :)

Comment: If the rest endpoint will only ever be called by cron, why have a rest endpoint at all? Spring does have scheduler capabilities. It seems to me that you may be better off use that and then potentially adding a rest endpoint to kick jobs on demand

Comment: @Leon Yes, Spring does have scheduler capabilities. Probably, this is what i am looking for. Here is the Spring guide i found which is very good: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/. Thank you for suggesting this!

Comment: As an addition to that, you can use Quartz which have a database backend which ensures that only 1 request is triggered.